# Identify limited columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to determine if a column is limited with several values. Like sex=male, female. Is there any query to identify such columns. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you mean if there is a CHECK constraint on the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the `CHECK` constraints - you can find those like this:

```
SELECT 
    TableName = t.name,
    ColumnName = c.name,
    cc.name ,
    cc.create_date ,
    cc.definition 
FROM 
    sys.check_constraints cc
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON cc.parent_object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON c.object_id = cc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = cc.parent_column_id
```

This will list the table name, column name, name of the check constraint, when it was created, and what its definition is.

Comment: Yes i mean the check constraint on column,thanks.